# Como relaciono três tabelas?

Tags: sql

Tenho três tabelas.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notem que se eu realizar um INNER JOIN nas três tabelas, iria me retornar apenas o produto 1 (Roteador), o qual está presente nas três tabelas.
Entretanto, eu precisaria que ele me retornasse todos os resultados, mas sem repetir informações. Ex.:

Se eu tenho 7 Roteadores na tabela `estoque1` e 9 roteadores na tabela `estoque2`, eu precisaria que o resultado final fosse 16 roteadores.

E também precisaria que retornasse todos os resultados que estivesse relacionados com a tabela `cadastro_produtos`.

O resultado esperado seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso proceder neste caso?

Comment: Neto, qual  SQL você usa? SQL-server, Mysql ou outro.

Comment: Uso o MySql. Aplicação web

Comment: Não Testei mais acho que isso resolve:

SELECT produto.id,produto.nome,sum(estoquegeral.quantidade) quantidade 
 FROM cadastro_produto as produto 
 LEFT JOIN 
 ( 
  (SELECT c_prod,quantidade FROM estoque1)
   UNION
  (SELECT c_prod,quantidade FROM estoque2)
 ) as estoquegeral
 ON estoquegeral.c_prod = produto.id
GROUP BY produto.id,produto.nome
ORDER BY produto.id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
Select
p.id,
p.nome,
sum(coalesce(e1.quantidade,0)+coalesce(e2.quantidade,0)) as Quantidade
from cadastro_produtos p
left outer join estoque1 e1 on e1.c_prod = p.id
left outer join estoque2 e2 on e2.c_prod = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.nome
```

***Mas*** aconselho a remover uma das tabelas de estoque, tendo apenas uma: `estoques`
onde teria mais uma coluna para identificar qual o estoque o item pertence. Ficando assim:

**Produto**

```
id* | nome | 
1   | roteador |
2   | mouse |
```

**Estoque**

```
estoque_id*|produto_id*|quantidade|responsavel
1          |    1      |     7    | fulano
1          |    2      |     1    | ciclano
1          |    6      |     3    | xxxxx
2          |    1      |     9    | xxxxx
```

Answer (score 3):

tente assim, veja se atende ao que você quer:

```
Select
p.id,
p.nome,
sum(coalesce(e1.quantidade,0)+coalesce(e2.quantidade,0)) as Quantidade
from cadastro_produtos p
left outer join estoque1 e1 on e1.c_prod = p.id
left outer join estoque2 e2 on e2.c_prod = p.id
GROUP BY p.id HAVING quantidade > 0
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito. Era o que eu precisava. Vou estudar o uso do LEFT JOIN

Comment: Fico feliz em poder ajudar! Bons estudos!

Answer (score 0):

Substitur o `INNER JOIN` pelo [FULL OUTER JOIN](http://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-join-entenda-como-funciona-o-retorno-dos-dados/31006) vai resolver teu problema.